# classinstance.__dict__ returns empty dictionary

Tags: python, class, dictionary

When I define a class with variables already assign, instantiate it and use `__dict__` to get variables as a dictionary, I get an empty list.

```
In [5]:

class A(object):
    a = 1
    b = 2
    text = "hello world"

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        pass

x = A()
x.__dict__

Out[5]:
{}
```

But when I declare variables in `__init__` and use `__dict__` it returns variables which were assigned after instantiation of class.

```
In [9]:

class A(object):
    a = 1
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def test(self):
        self.b = 2
        self.text = "hello world"


x = A()
x.test()
x.__dict__

Out[9]:
{'b': 2, 'text': 'hello world'}
```

Why is that `__dict__` returning only variables declared after instantiation of class

**Edit Answer**:

When an instance is created like `x = A()`

`x.__dict__` stores all the instance attributes.

`A.__dict__` stores the class attributes

Comment: Because the others are class attributes, not instance attributes.

Comment: Because `instance.__dict__` only holds *instance* attributes. Your first example created *class* attributes, and these are shared between all instances.

Comment: Because `instance.__dict__` only holds *instance* attributes. Your first example created *class* attributes, and these are shared between all instances.

Comment: Why is this question closed, as duplicate. That question doesn't even answer my question

Answer (score 2):

Pls try `A.__dict__` to get all class attributes,

```
x = A()
x.__dict__
```

here you are calling `__dict__` method on  A's instance. So the variables associated with that instance should be displayed...

`self.b`, `self.text` are instance variables which are specific to particular instance only..

Comment: then use `x.__class__.__dict__` if only have access to instance